# how to change navigation bar title according to uitableview row selection?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've added a navigation bar on my view controller. But when I run my code, this line: `let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell` has problems. Any idea how I can add or change the navigation bar title according to my selection? My `UITableView` is a list of array. 
Although build successfully, it kept showing me

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Besides that, how do I change the navigation bar title according to my selection in the `UITableView`?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.destination is DetailVC {

        let destination = segue.destination as! DetailVC
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        destination.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text

        destination.developer = developerArray[(myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        myTableView.deselectRow(at: myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**VIEW CONTROLLER CODE**

```
import UIKit


class Developers {
    var developerName: String?
    var developerEmail: String?
    var developerBalance: Float?
    var developerHP: String?

    init(dvName: String, dvHP: String) {
        self.developerName = dvName
        self.developerHP = dvHP
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

   var developerArray = [Developers]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


        let developer = Developers(dvName: "Developer 0", dvHP: "Phone Number: #0")
        developerArray.append(developer)

        let developer1 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 1", dvHP: "Phone Number: #1")
        developerArray.append(developer1)

        let developer2 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 2", dvHP: "Phone Number: #2")
        developerArray.append(developer2)

        let developer3 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 3", dvHP: "Phone Number: #3")
        developerArray.append(developer3)

        let developer4 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 4", dvHP: "Phone Number: #4")
        developerArray.append(developer4)

        let developer5 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 5", dvHP: "Phone Number: #5")
        developerArray.append(developer5)

        let developer6 = Developers(dvName: "Developer 6", dvHP: "Phone Number: #6")
        developerArray.append(developer6)

        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self

    }

    //MARK:- UITableView methods

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return developerArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell")
        if cell == nil {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        }

            cell?.textLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerHP

            return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let detailVC = DetailVC()
        detailVC.titleStringViaSegue = self.developerArray[indexPath.row].developerName
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DevToDetail", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailVC {
            destination.developer = developerArray[(myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            myTableView.deselectRow(at: myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: has problems 0-- what problem

Comment: it kept showing this when i run it although its built successfully:
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell")
        if cell == nil {
            
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        }
        
            cell?.textLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerHP
        
            return cell!
    }

Comment: can you post your viewController code

Comment: hi i edited and posted my view controller code. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the your DetailVC

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!
    var titleStringViaSegue: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.title = self.titleStringViaSegue
    }
}
```

Change your `didselect` method like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
        destination.titleStringViaSegue = developerArray[indexPath.row].name
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
```

You can give your storyboard ID like this. [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202316/discussion-on-answer-by-rushabh-shah-how-to-change-navigation-bar-title-accordin).

Answer (score 1):

Use `didSelect` function of `tableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "<StoryboardID>") as! Destination //StoryboardID of Destination
    destination.navigationTitle = developerArray[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create navigationTitle property on  destination controller.

```
 class Destination: UIViewController {
        var navigationTitle  = ""

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationItem.title =  navigationTitle

       }

    }
```

check if title available while pushing destination Controller

```
if segue.destination is DetailVC {

            let destination = segue.destination as! DetailVC

            if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell , let title = cell.textLabel?.text {
                destination.navigationTitle = title
            }


            destination.developer = developerArray[(myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            myTableView.deselectRow(at: myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: it worked, but my detail screen still doesnt show a navigation bar title based on my selection :/

Comment: can you try self.title = navigationTitle

Comment: it still doesnt pass my selection to the navigation bar

Comment: can you print your selected title on if statement and check if printed successfully

Comment: how do i do that? sorry, im really new to swift

Comment: if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell , let title = cell.textLabel?.text {
            print(title)
            destination.navigationItem.title = title
        }

Comment: it doesnt work :/ it still wont change my navigation bar title according to my selection

Comment: build failed, i really dont know what is the problem :(